# Shift Registers - How does one pronounce QH'

Tags: shift-register, 74hc595

In the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/sn74hc595-446004.pdf) for the 74HC595 shift register, pin 9 is labeled "Q<sub>H'</sub>" (not to be confused with pin 7, labeled "Q<sub>H</sub>" without the "<sub>'</sub>").  I understand that this pin outputs the current contents of the register as new data is shifted in for the purpose of daisy-chaining registers, but...

What I'm not sure of is, what would a professional engineer call this pin in verbal conversation with another engineer?  Maybe "Dump pin?", or "Exit strategy?", or maybe "Que Aych Huzzahh!"  Probably none of the above, which is why I'm asking.

Thanks.

Comment: Quebec Hotel Prime. ;^) Queen How Prime for old folks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's basically doing the function of "Serial Out", so you could call it that.

As written it would be "Q" "H" "prime". The `'` is likely the [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) symbol, something used for many different things, but in logic diagrams it typically indicates that something is a from a different state, or next clock cycle, or as the Wiki article puts it:

> x′ generally means something related to or derived from x